# Quartz SimpleTrigger event triggerred immediately even though the repeatInterval is some time later

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a simpleTrigger defined. The repeatInterval is 10 seconds.

I noticed at some situation, after one event fired, it immediately fired another one (not 10 seconds later), 3rd even fired at 10 seconds later.

Any idea about what happened, and how to correct this behavior?
I don't know whether it is a mis-fire situation (I didn't see the error), if it is how to correct this behaviour, I don't want the event fired immediately after that one.

When running the program I see the job fired at 1365178800586 milliseconds.

then fired at 1365178800593 milliseconds, ie at appoximately the same time.

subsequently fired at 1365178810583 milliseconds, ie at approximately 10 seconds after the first call.

Java code snippet:

```
String testJobname = "testJob";
JobDetail testJobDetail = new JobDetail();
testJobDetail.setGroup(this.getClass().getName());
testJobDetail.setName(testJobname);
testJobDetail.setJobClass(TestJob.class);

final JobDataMap data = new JobDataMap();
data.put(CheckLimits.class.getName(), checkLimitsCmd);
testJobDetail.setJobDataMap(data);

Trigger testTrigger = new SimpleTrigger(testJobDetail.getName(),
 testJobDetail.getGroup(), SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY,
 10000);
```

Comment: are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you should be using TriggerBuilder and ScheduleBuilder instead of instantiating SimpleTrigger directly.

```
Schedule schedule = SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(10).build();
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(testJobDetail).usingJobData(data).withSchedule(schedule).build();
```

The Quartz documentation have some good examples in the Javadoc code, check out this for more information - 
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/SimpleScheduleBuilder.html